# VBScript strCommand como puedo poner comillas dentro?

Tags: vbscript, vbs

Cómo puedo poner comillas dentro de sendkeys?

Por ejemplo:

```
strCommand = "cmd /k Hola"bro" como estas 'va' bien las cosas "bro"? "
```

Por que cuando hago eso me dice que se esperaba ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es concatenar el `string` con las comillas necesarias, por ejemplo:

```
strCommand = "cmd /k Hola" & """" & "bro" & """" & " como estas 'va' bien las cosas " & """" & "bro" & """" & "? "
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió